# What is the unique ID of Twitter's Posts?

Tags: twitter

I am just curious to know how Twitter handles the unique ID for its posts?
I am making a guess that it has `unsigned Bigdecimal` as its unique id for all the status/posts. Because when we click on any of the posts, the URL is appended by `/status/<unique-id>`.

I made the guess for `BigDecimal` because if we open any recent post, the unique number at the end of URL is much higher than an `Integer`. This is one [example](https://twitter.com/MensHealthMag/status/964786499668541440)

Is anything I am getting wrong here?

And if I am guessing it right, isn't Twitter going to consume all the unique IDs soon?

Comment: https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tweets/data-dictionary/overview/tweet-object it is either `id` , or `id_str` (intended for platforms that cant handle 64bit integers)

Comment: You can read more about Twitter's Snowflake IDs on the developer site here https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/basics/twitter-ids with the original announcement here https://blog.twitter.com/engineering/en_us/a/2010/announcing-snowflake.html (although the code has since been fully rewritten and has not been re-released externally to https://github.com/twitter/snowflake)